# disable margin-right gutter-width value when using the span-columns set at total-columns?

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass

Using the susy compass addon, when use the `span-columns` mixin to be set to `$total-columns` how can I disable the margin-right value being set by `$gutter-width`?

At the moment my code is:

```
.element{
@include span-columns(12);
}
```

results in

```
.element{
width: 100%
margin-right: 2.12766%;
}
```

ideally i would like margin-right not to exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to use `span-columns()` at all in this case. Block elements span 100% width by default, and there is no reason for any of the other properties (float & margin) that are part of the mixin.

That said, simply add `omega` and the right margin will go away. Still, it's a bulky way to achieve any of the goals you might be after. If you need it to clear other elements, you should use the simple `clear: both;`. If you need it to wrap internal floats, use a clearfix (Compass has several).

Comment: hey, thanks for this. I'm getting used to susy and I guess right now I feel I should be using everything susy can offer when I should be using the simpler approach.